# When is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: analysis

Let $\alpha$ be a nonreal algebraic number. I'm interested in conditions that imply that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. I'm particularly interested algebraic integer $\alpha$.

This is what I know so far:

- if there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha^n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$;
- algebraic integers of degree two don't satisfy the condition, although algebraic nonintegers of degree two may.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If and only if either $\alpha$ has degree at least $3$ or has degree $2$ and is not an algebraic integer. The key lemma is that a subgroup $A$ of a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$ such that $A$ spans $V$ is either discrete or dense in a subspace of $V$, and in the first case it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ where $n = \dim V$. Now observe that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ if and only if $\alpha^2$ is an integer linear combination of $\alpha$ and $1$, and furthermore that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ cannot be dense only in a $1$-dimensional subspace because for any such subspace it must also be dense in $\alpha$ times that subspace.

Comment: The subgroups $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Z\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb R^2$ are counter examples to your claim.

Comment: @Olivier: I just edited the claim after noticing that.

Comment: Would you be able to give a reference for this "key lemma"? I am not sure where to look for such general results.

Comment: @Rein: this is overkill but it follows from the closed subgroup theorem in Lie theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem Probably a more elementary argument is possible too.